# Sqlite database designing

Tags: android, sqlite

My app loads and parses data to an Article objects. I need to store articles in a database to access them offline.
Each article has fields:

- Title (Text)
- Text (Text)
- Date (Text in specific format)
- Tags (Text)
- Link (Text)
- Preview image (Blob)
- Full image (Blob)
- Related articles

Each **related** article has fields:

- Title (Text)
- Link (Text)
- Preview image (Blob)

  1. Should I create a new database for related articles or store them in the existing database? What is better for performance and what is better for designing?
  2. Should I store preview and full image? Or maybe it's better to scale existing full image to preview format in app? (app performance vs extra data storage)

I know that it usually depends on the circumstances, but I want to know what is usually the best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:**
One article has many related articles so here relationship is 1 to many (1:M).
Keep two table in your database :

> Article : to store articles data. 
> RelatedArticle : to map related
>   articles of some article

Lets say you have article table with data:

id   name
a   aaa
b   bbb
c   ccc
d   ddd
e   eee

and you have articles c e and b related to article a then this relationship stored in related article table as:

id realtedTo(id of article)
a   c
a   e
a   b

**Regarding your second question:**
My suggestion as per my experience if you are fetching image from server, then fetch its thumbnail(preview image) which has small size. If it is need to be shown in full screen then again request to server full scale image.
Benefits of this approach that your articles list loads fast with thumbnails , and if user clicks on some article you can download full image to show in article details.